# Azure Mobile Services - Why TokenLifetime is not checked on tokens I issued?

Tags: authentication, sms, asp.net-identity, azure-mobile-services

I followed [this official tutorial](https://manage.windowsazure.com/@yaronlevidevgmail.onmicrosoft.com#Workspaces/MobileServicesExtension/apps/meetztesting/dashboard), that shows how to issue custom tokens.

Everything works great, but with one little problem.
The built-in authentication layer in mobile service dose not seem to check for **token expire time** and block expired tokens.

In CustomLoginProvider.cs I even tried to minimize the token life time to 10 seconds like so:

```
public CustomLoginProvider(IServiceTokenHandler tokenHandler)
    : base(tokenHandler)
{
    this.TokenLifetime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10);
}
```

But this seems to be ignored, and I can call methods on the server as much as I like with the same token issued to me.

Comment: Meet the same problem in my project...

Did you found any solution?

Comment: Added question about issue [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-get-started-custom-authentication/)